# Git Clone specific folders from src repo to dest repo with preserving history

Tags: git, git-clone

I have 2 working repositories, `repo1` and `repo2`.

I want to clone only a few folders from repo1 to repo2 along with the commit history of those files.

example:

`copy repo1/src/build` to `repo2/src1/build`

I tried cloning everything with histories but then there were lot of merge conflicts, and it was a nightmare. Hence, I want the specific content of the repo1 to be in repo2/src1 folder with its history and I'll keep the ones I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a one-time action, or will you need to keep the cloned folder up-to-date with the repo1 upstream?

Comment: @JimRedmond This is a one time action. Will be deprecating repo1 once the move is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the same with `git-filter-repo`, follow these steps:

This guide assumes that you have clone repository A and that you have folder for repository B.

In repository B, add a remote connection to repository A as a branch .

```
git remote add repo-A-branch /path/to/example-repo-A
```

Create a new branch containing only the history and files of directory 1:

```
git filter-repo --path example-dir-1 --refs repo-A-branch --branch-name example-dir-1-branch
```

This will create a new branch in your repository B containing only the history and files of directory 1 from repository A.

Merge the new branch into the master branch of repository B

```
git checkout master
git merge example-dir-1-branch
```

Clean up by removing the remote connection to repository A

```
git remote rm repo-A-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

This [blog page](https://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/) contains what you want to achieve.

Let me quote important parts:

> **Goal:** Move directory 1 from Git repository A to Git repository B.
>
> **Constraints**:
>
> - Git repository A contains other directories that we don’t want to move.
> - Preserve the Git commit history for the directory we are moving.

These steps refer to the code below, check the page for full instructions:

> 1. **Make a copy of repository A**. This allows you to mess with it without worrying about mistakes too much.
> 2. Delete the link to the original repository to avoid accidentally making any remote changes (line 3).
> 3. Line 4 [...] goes through your history and files, removing anything that is not in directory

```
git clone <git repository A url>
cd <git repository A directory>
git remote rm origin
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory 1> -- --all
mkdir <directory 1>
mv * <directory 1>
git add .
git commit
```

These steps refer to the code below, check the page for full instructions:

> 1. Make a copy of repository B if you don’t have one already.
> 2. On line 3, you’ll create a remote connection to repository A as a branch in repository B.
> 3. Pull from this branch (containing only the directory you want to move) into repository B.  The pull copies both files and history.

```
git clone <git repository B url>
cd <git repository B directory>
git remote add repo-A-branch <git repository A directory>
git pull repo-A-branch master --allow-unrelated-histories
git remote rm repo-A-branch
```

Other references:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch
- https://www-acc.gsi.de/wiki/Applications/AppHowToGitMoveWithHistory

Comment: The `git-filter-branch` docs suggest that it isn't recommended: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning . Maybe https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/ would work better?

Comment: @JimRedmond Thanks for the hint.  Oh yeah, the original blog post is about 10 years old and the content was reposted in the referenced article a year ago. I have never tried this myself but will refer to your link again once I need it.

Comment: @JimRedmond For now these two repositories are independent, and repo1 is being used. i am moving it to a repo2. I don't want to delete any contents of repo 1. Under these conditions would your solution git-filter-repo be helpful?

Comment: Seems to be just a better tool, see project's intro: "git filter-repo is a versatile tool for rewriting history [...]. It roughly falls into the same space of tool as git filter-branch but without [...] poor performance, with far more capabilities [...] git filter-repo is now recommended by the git project instead of git filter-branch." See the [project's cheatsheet](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#cheat-sheet-conversion-of-examples-from-the-filter-branch-manpage) to convert the other method.